# Public key not found error when installing Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install the clover plugin for eclipse (version 4.20.0) and I'm following the steps on https://openclover.org/doc/manual/latest/eclipse--openclover-for-eclipse-in-10-minutes.html

However after I finish the install wizard, I get this error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for -5034155639734203956.
OK
```

I've tried both using the url and downloading the .zip manually, both result in this error.